# How to separate the selection of a duplicate mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I just duplicated a part of a mesh but as I select one of them, both are being selected. I learned about the 'P' hotkey, however, it's not working in my case. I'm using the latest version of Blender.
I used the 'P' button for the selection menu but it's not working.
Please tell me another way to do it

Project link:http://www.mediafire.com/file/mcqsc88v7rb911j/FirstProject.blend/file

[image]

Comment: please give us some screenshots or share your file, because we can't help you without more informations

Comment: P hotkey obviously works. It's a stable feature of Blender and always have been, so you're doing something wrong.

Comment: here is the project link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/mcqsc88v7rb911j/FirstProject.blend/file

Comment: This works exactly as expected. After hitting P>Selected.. the top section still shows (inactive) selected, but as an _object_, not as part of the mesh you are editing. As a new object, it has a new name: 'torus.001'...

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to edit mode for separate by 'P' to work. If you just want to separate the top portion in your screenshot, go to edit mode, select those vertices that you want to separate, press P and choose 'Selection'